# QML PageIndicator fit size in Rectangle

Tags: qt, qml

The SwipeView can have multiple Text pages (more than 20 which will be correctly added in `Component.onCompleted`) and the corresponding PageIndicator has to fit in a rather small Rectangle (`id: swipeRect`) in a ListView. I made a custom delegate for the PageIndicator, however I am not able to make it fit inside the Rectangle i.e. each dot of the PageIndicator changes width based on number of pages, but the total PageIndicator does not fit inside `swipeRect.width`. Here is my simplified code:

```
...
Rectangle{
  id: swipeRect
  anchors.fill: parent
  color: 'transparent' //'red'
  SwipeView{
    id: swipeRectView
    anchors.horizontalCenter: swipeRect.horizontalCenter
    anchors.top: swipeRect.top
    clip: true
  }
  PageIndicator {
    id: indicator
    width: swipeRect.width
    count: swipeRectView.count
    currentIndex: swipeRectView.currentIndex
    anchors.bottom: swipeRect.bottom
    anchors.horizontalCenter: swipeRect.horizontalCenter

    delegate: Rectangle{
      implicitWidth: swipeRect.width / swipeRectView.count
      implicitHeight: 3
      color: 'blue'
      opacity: index == indicator.currentIndex ? 0.9 : 0.2
      }
    }

  Component.onCompleted: addViews(swipeRectView)
}
```

Here is the actual output:

[image: actual output]

And the Rectangle `swipeRect` inside which the PageIndicator should match is marked in red:

[image: output to match]

Comment: My guess is that you are not taking padding/spacing into account when you do this: `implicitWidth: swipeRect.width / swipeRectView.count`.

Comment: @JarMan and how do you think should I handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, I solved the problem by adding these lines in `PageIndicator`:

```
padding: 0
spacing: 3
```

and the `delegate` I changed like:

```
implicitWidth: (swipeRect.width - ((swipeRectView.count-1)*(indicator.spacing))) / swipeRectView.count
```

where spacing is my self chosen value. Now it fits perfectly inside the red rectangle!